# Lifetime of http request

Tags: node.js

In learning node and working through a few examples, I have a prototype which is working perfectly in test but I am worried that it is working 'by accident'.

The code, (heavily stripped down) boils down to the following

```
function CheckValue(){
  var req=http.request({/*some options*/},
                       function (resp){
                       resp.on('data',
                               function (s){
                         /* process the response */
                       })});
  /* Tweak a few headers here. */
  req.end();
}
```

now if I understand the documents correctly - the request is actually sent to the server at the point of `req.end()` and the callback is not processed until data is received.

So; if there is *significant* delay between the request being issued and the response being received could the `req` object be garbage collected? If so would the callback presumably not be called? Or, looking at it from another angle: *does node internally maintain any references to http requests until they are complete?*

(The code is deliberately written in a *fire and forget* manner, with `req` being internally scoped within the function and not saved in any global scope. It would be feasible to store the request in an array and delete the request during `resp.on('end',...)` but I would rather avoid the complication and overhead.)

Comment: you can easily use http://www.deelay.me/ to verify your thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. See the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_agent):

> Class: http.Agent - 
>   An Agent is responsible for managing connection persistence and reuse for HTTP clients. It maintains a queue of pending requests for a given host and port, reusing a single socket connection for each until the queue is empty, at which time the socket is either destroyed or put into a pool where it is kept to be used again for requests to the same host and port. Whether it is destroyed or pooled depends on the keepAlive option.

There is a [global Agent instance](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_globalagent) which is used as the default for all HTTP client requests. So the bottom line is, this Agent instance will handle and store the reference of the request objects, and hence the req object will not be garbage collected.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you.